# How do you format output string in bash script for input by another script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I need to unzip a bunch of student assignment (jar) files so that I can use a script to submit the contents to the Moss (Stanford) plagiarism detection server. I did the same thing in Java which was trivial but I'm trying to re-implement to as a bash script.

I am trying to do the following:

1. Get a list of student names (each student has a directory).
2. In each student directory, sub-directories exist numbered from 1 to the
   latest submission. I need to get the directory with the highest
   number.
3. Inside of each of those submission directories contains a
   jar file that I need. I copy each jar into a temp directory with the
   same name as the student and unzip it.
4. I need that temp directory listing formatted as a string in the form

   /tempDir/studentName1/*.languageExt /tempDir/studentName2/*.languageExt

The student directory has the basic structure:

```
Student_Root_Directory: 
Student1 
Student2 
    Student1
        Sub-Directories: 1 2 3 4 5 
        1: student1.jar
        2: student1.jar
        ...
    Student2
        Sub-Directories: 1 2 3
        1. student2.jar
        ...
```

To do the first 3 steps above I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Extract all jar files into a temp directory called /home/moss/tempJarFiles/studentName
# $1 is the command line argument that contains the path to the institution submission dir.
# $2 is the language extension: .c, .cpp, .java, .py

students=`ls $1`
student_dir=$1
languageExt=$2
mossDir="/home/moss"
tempDir="/home/moss/tempJarStorage"
for student in $students
        do
        latestSubmissionDir=`ls -t $student_dir/$student | head -1`
        for jarDir in $latestSubmissionDir
                do
                mkdir $tempDir/$student
                cp $student_dir/$student/$jarDir/*.jar $tempDir/$student
                unzip -d $tempDir/$student/ -o -j $tempDir/$student/$student.jar *.$languageExt
                rm $tempDir/$student/$student.jar
                done
        done
```

...which results in a number of student directories being created in a temp directory that contains only the unzipped contents for the student submissions. 
I need the ls output of the new temp directories formatted as a string that contains:

```
/tempDir/studentName1/\*.languageExt /tempDir/studentName2/\*.languageExt
```

I have tried variations on

```
find "$tempDir" -iname "*.$languageExt" -printf "%p/*.$languageExt"
```

using iname and not - but I either have output that contains extra directory information such as $tempDir/*.languageExt (when I just need the subdirectories $tempDir/$studentName/*.languageExt) or I have output where the path for every source file is also listed such as:

$tempDir/$studentName/studentNameA.java
$tempDir/$studentName/studentNameB.java
when I only need 
$tempDir/$studentName/*.java

I think this should be really easy and I'm just over thinking it. Any hints for improving the script also appreciated.

Comment: The loop over jardir doesn't make sense: latestSubmissionDir is a single word and not a list of words.

Comment: `echo /tempDir/*/*."$languageExt"` ? Also, paths can contain spaces, special characters, etc... (quote your variables).

Comment: @user829755 You are correct. I didn't even notice it because it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a revised version of the script hat may work:

```bsh
#/bin/bash

# Extract all jar files into a temp directory called /home/moss/tempJarFiles/studentName
# $1 is the command line argument that contains the path to the institution submission dir.
# $2 is the language extension: c, cpp, java, py

students_dir=$1
languageExt=$2

studentPathsT=( "$students_dir"/*/ )

mossDir='/home/moss'
tempDir='/home/moss/tempJarStorage'

for studentPathT in "${studentPathsT[@]}"; do
  student=$(basename "$studentPathT")
  mkdir "$tempDir/$student"
  submissionDirsT=( "$studentPathT"*/ )
  latestSubmissionDirT=${submissionDirsT[${#submissionDirsT[@]-1]}
  cp "$latestSubmissionDirT"*.jar "$tempDir/$student/"
  unzip -d "$tempDir/$student/" -o -j "$tempDir/$student/*.jar" "*.$languageExt"
  rm "$tempDir/$student"/*.jar
done

# Note that at this point `"$tempDir"/*/*.$languageExt` would expand
# to all extracted submission files, across all students.

# Finally, output each student's extracted files as an unexpanded glob à la
# /{tempDir}/{studentName1}/*.{languageExt}
for pT in "$tempDir"/*/; do
  echo "$pT*.$languageExt"
  # Note: If there is a chance that your filenames contain 
  #       embedded newlines (rare in practice) using `echo` won't work properly
  #       as @Charles Duffy points out.
  #       If that is a concern, use
  #           printf '%s\0' "$pT*.$languageExt"
  #       and process the output with a utility that can process NUL characters
  #       as separators, such as `xargs -0`.
done
```

- It avoids using `ls` and only uses *pathname expansion* and array variables so as to properly deal with paths that contain embedded spaces and other shell metacharacters.
- suffix `...T` in variable names indicates that a particular path or array of paths is **T**erminated, i.e, that it ends in a `/`.
- The assumption is that the numbered subdirectories do not go beyond `9`, as the implicit lexical sorting of pathname expansion is relied upon; if the numbers go higher, explicit numerical sorting must be applied.
- Note that the globs (pathname patterns) passed to `unzip` are intentionally *double-quoted*, as they should be interpreted by `unzip`, not the shell.
- Note that, based on your original code, I've assumed that `$languageExt` does NOT start with `.` (e.g., `cpp` rather than `.cpp`), despite what your comment says.

Comment: Using newline-delimited filename lists, as created by using `echo`, isn't ideal -- UNIX filenames may contain literal newlines, and so a maliciously-crafted filename can emit content read as other names into your stream. Much, much better to use NUL as a delimiter -- or `printf '%q\n' "$p"`, to generate an eval-safe name on a single line.

Comment: It bypasses the problem, up until the last line when you use echo. Above that point, though, you're doing everything perfectly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sorry, I had already deleted my earlier comment (saying that the use of pathname expansion and array variables bypassed the problem) when you responded: I realized there was indeed a problem with `${submissionDirsT[@]: -1}`, which wouldn't have preserved embedded newlines; I've since corrected that. As for your point: I've added a caveat after the `echo` statement; using `printf '%q\n'`, though, would add an additional level of quoting that would need to be resolved, so I suggested `printf '%s\0'` instead.

Comment: Thank you.  This is exactly what I was looking for and I learned some things as well. And you were correct about the language ext. I had added it in after the fact to make things clearer but it had the opposite effect. Thanks again.

Comment: CORRECTION to my own earlier claim: `${someArray[@]: -1}` to refer to an array's last element DOES correctly preserve embedded newlines (and is generally preferable to `${someArray[${#someArray[@]}-1]}` in that it doesn't require the array indices to be contiguous).